# Finding the distribution of $Y=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X_i\sim\chi^{2}(p_i)$, $i=1,\dots,n$.  I'm being asked to find the distribution of this sum $Y$.  I'm just curious but how would I go about approaching this problem?  I ask because there's a gamma function in the denominator of the pdf and an $x$ and exponential term which doesn't seem like you can add them as easily as I thought and come up with something.  Can someone give me some help?

Answer (score 1):

$\chi^2(p)$ is distributed as a sum of $p$ independent squared standard normal variables. So adding (independent!) $\chi^2(p_1), \chi^2(p_2),\dots,\chi^2(p_n)$, you get sum of $p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n$ independent squared standard normal variables, which is $\chi^2(p_1+p_2+\dots+p_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the moment generating function, it is often the easiest way when working with the sum of independent random variables. (Don't read past this point if you want to try it yourself before)

Assuming the X's are independent:

$M_Y(t)=E(e^{tY})=E(e^{t\sum X_i})=\prod E(e^{tX_i})=\prod M_{X_i}(t)$

The mgf of a chi-quare is $(1-2t)^{-k/2}$ with k=$p_i$ in your case.

Then $M_Y(t)=\prod (1-2t)^{-p_i/2}=(1-2t)^{-(\sum p_i)/2}$ which is a chi-square with parameter $k=\sum p_i$